# Проверить вхождение элементов в массив

Tags: функции, javascript

Нужно реализовать функцию isInArray, проверяющую вхождение элементов в массив. Первый аргумент функции - массив, последующие - элементы, вхождение в массив которых проверяется. Функция возвращает true, если все аргументы, кроме первого, являются элементами массива.

Пример работы:

```
isInArray([1], 1); // true
isInArray([1], 1, 2); // false
isInArray([1, 2], 1, 2); // true
```

Я сделал, но вариант с объектом у меня не получился.

Пишет:

> Замечание:
>
> Не возвращает true для такого случая
>
> var obj = {}; isInArray([obj, 1],
> obj);

Вот мой код:

---

```
var obj={};
var arr = [1, 2, 3,obj];

function isInArray(arr) {

    var obj1 = [arr, 1, 2,obj];

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < obj1.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == obj1[j]) {
                return true;
            } else return false;
        }

    }
}
isInArray(arr);
```

Comment: @Yres, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подсказки:

1. [`indexOf()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) - метод для поиска элемента в массиве;
2. [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) – похожий на массив объект, содержащий все переданные в ф-ю параметры.

Upd. готовое [решение](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/1ahg08hh/), но если просто спишете, ничему не научитесь.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри здесь уже готовые реализации [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.ru/#arrays)